# Can you assign the LIKE operator's ESCAPE character at the statement, table, or database level?

Tags: sqlite

The title has it ...
Can you assign the `LIKE` operator's `ESCAPE` character at the statement, table, or database level ... or can you only assign it per-`LIKE`?

Answer (score 0):

No. `LIKE` applies to values from rows. The table name in `SELECT` is an exact lookup, and does not support anything like `LIKE`. Similarly, column and database  names are also matched exactly.